# Error when deploying krakenjs on Heroku

Tags: node.js, heroku, kraken.js

I'm recently trying krakenjs and Heroku but when i try to deploy but an error message gets displayed:

http://pastebin.com/6CPXN4Qs

I don't know if it has anything to do with it, but my GitHub repo is private.

Also this is my package.json:

```
{
"name": "App",
"version": "0.0.1",
"main": "index.js",
"scripts": {
    "test": "grunt test"
},
"dependencies": {
    "connect-redis":"~2.2.0",
    "kraken-js": "^1.0.1",
    "kraken-devtools": "^1.0.0",
    "engine-munger": "^0.2.0",
    "express": "^4.3.0",
    "express-session": "latest",
    "dustjs-helpers": "~1.2.0",
    "dustjs-linkedin": "~2.3.6",
    "lusca": "latest",
    "requirejs": "~2.1.11",
    "adaro": "~0.1.5",
    "localizr": "~0.1.0",
    "node-sass": "~0.8.4",
    "mongoose": "3.8",
    "ejs" : "latest",
    "consolidate" : "latest",
    "sequelize" : "latest",
    "mysql" : "latest",
    "orm" : "latest",
    "MD5" : "latest",
    "cowsay" : "latest"
},
"devDependencies": {
    "mocha": "^1.18.0",
    "supertest": "^0.9.0",
    "grunt-contrib-requirejs": "~0.4.3",
    "grunt-dustjs": "~1.2.0",
    "grunt-config-dir": "~0.3.2",
    "grunt-contrib-clean": "~0.5.0",
    "grunt-sass": "~0.12.1",
    "grunt-localizr": "~0.1.0",
    "grunt-mocha-cli": "~1.5.0",
    "grunt-copy-to": "0.0.10",
    "grunt": "~0.4.1",
    "grunt-contrib-jshint": "~0.10.0",
    "bower": "latest",
    "grunt-cli": "latest",
    "gulp": "latest",
    "yo": "latest"
},
"generator-kraken": {
    "version": "1.1.2",
    "template": "dustjs",
    "css": "sass",
    "js": "requirejs",
    "task": "grunt"
}
}
```

Please help me :'(